# Symfony form with an extra input for an entity

Tags: php, html, forms, symfony

I am trying to build a form to create a competition.
The competition has a discipline, it could have many categories and in each category could have different rounds. Each round could have many matches as the user want to. So, there should be an number input related to each round.

```
$builder->add('name')
        ->add('date',DateType::class,array('format' => 'ddMMMMyyyy'))
        ->add('discipline', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'Bundle:Discipline', 'choice_label' => 'name'))
        ->add('category', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'Bundle:Category', 'choice_label' => 'name', 'multiple' => true, 'expanded' => true))
        ->add('round', EntityType::class, array('class' => 'Bundle:Round'...

        ->add('submit',SubmitType::class)
```

e.g.

```html
<label for="round_1">Qualify Matches:</label><input type="number"><br>
<label for="round_2">Semi-Final Matches:</label><input type="number"><br>
<label for="round_3">Final Matches:</label><input type="number">
```

Any ideas? 
Thanks.

Comment: You need a form collection: https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html

Comment: I am trying but I don't see the way to do it with CollectionType. To add a number field next to each RoundType to know how many matches are in each one.

Comment: You're going to create a new type that has your round type embedded and the number field, then you use the collection with this new type you created.